# How to extend the core customer table?

Tags: shopware

I created a custom table with additional settings for customers. Next I added a field to the customer core table in which I'd like to store the id choice per customer. I extended with EntityExtensionInterface the customerDefinition :

```
public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void
{
    $collection->add(
        (new OneToOneAssociationField(
            'customerSetting',
            'customer_setting',
            'id',
            WdtCustomerSettingsDefinition::class,
            true
        ))->addFlags(new Inherited())
    );
}

public function getDefinitionClass(): string
{
    return CustomerDefinition::class;
}
```

When I manually manipulate the customer table, with an id from my custom table in the added field, I can retrieve and use the settings from my custom table in the storefront.

For the backend I created a single select to the entity custom_table,

```
<sw-entity-single-select entity="wdt_customer_settings" v-model="customer.extensions.customerSetting.id" >
</sw-entity-single-select>
```

and with the manually 'injected' id from the custom table, this choice indicates indeed  'selected' However, after changing to another choice and saving results in an error: Customer could not be saved.

What am I missing?

Comment: I had issues with OneToOne in the past. Would you mind testing out OneToMany?

Comment: I wouldn't mind, but what should I put in for values?     $collection->add(
            (new OneToManyAssociationField(
                'customerSetting',
                WdtCustomerSettingsDefinition::class,
                'customerSetting',
                'id'
            ))->addFlags(new Inherited())
        );

Comment: Where should I define this OneToMany? And how? If I define in stead of the OneToOne in the EntityExtension class, I can't use it in the storefront

Comment: What exception do you get when you use it in the storefront?

Answer (score 0):

You should look always to the ajax responses. There is the explict error which is occured. Do you added some boilerplate code to check that your extensions is always available? Otherwise it would cause issues on new entities